# VBA: How to call multiple functions when a value in a drop down arrow is selected

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have the following code embedded in a specific sheet that calls the function `Form_Logo` whenever a selected option in the checklist in cell `N2` is changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N2")) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Range("N2")
            Case "Option 1": Form_Logo
            Case "Option 2": Form_Logo
            Case "Option 3": Form_Logo
        End Select
    End If

    End Sub
```

Now I'm interested in calling a second function whenever an option in the checklist is selected. This second function is called `Pull_News`.  How would you alter the above code so that everytime the checklist value is changed, a second function called `Pull_News` is triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be a little more detailed about exactly when the second sub should be called: only for specific choices, or for any choice?

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N2")) Is Nothing Then
        'For specific values (incorporating BigBen's comment)
        Select Case Range("N2")
            Case "Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"
               Form_Logo
        End Select
        Pull_News '  for any value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Tim. The order of the two functions does not matter

Comment: By "when" I really meant "under what circumstances"

Comment: Oh I see, whenever the value is changed in needs to be called. No matter what the value is